# telegram chat bot with webforms. Is it possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, telegram

Can I create a telegram chat bot with aspnet webforms on shared hosting ? Maybe with using hangfire or something to make it run continiously ? Or is it againts the nature of aspnet ?

thanks

Comment: Your question title says _"with winforms"_ while the text says _"with aspnet webforms"_ (as do the tags on the question).  You probably want to clean up the question title.  You might also want to look at ASP.NET MVC with Signal/R

Answer (score 0):

Even with simple if's and For loops you can do anything!

The question only is what are you trying to achieve and how much effort you're going to put in.